# Dynamically create arrays from an existing arrays values in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I have a array of unique values, e.g. "London Office", "Manchester Office" etc.
What I need to do is create a new array for every value inside the original array, where the name of each array is the value in the original array. I.e. so that the name of each array is:
"London Office", "Manchester Office" etc.

This would seem simple but is stumping me, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Arrays don't have names. Are you looking for some sort of dictionary that can hold arrays perhaps?

Comment: Apologies, I meant the variable name of the array, e.g. $ManchesterOffice where "ManchesterOffice" is taken from the value inside another array

Comment: I would strongly recommend _not_ using dynamically named variables. More so when your names might contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set-Variable` cmdlet. Or, create a global hash table and stuff arrays in its entries with keys from your initial array.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a hashtable - basically an unordered dictionary:

```
$Array = "London Office", "Manchester Office"

# Create an empty hashtable    
$Hashtable = @{}

foreach($item in $Array){
    # create hashtable entry with array $item as key/name, empty array as value
    $Hashtable[$item] = @()
}
```

Now you can access the individual arrays like this:

```
$Hashtable["Manchester Office"] += "New array item here"
```